# Simplify counting and appending to a list

Tags: python-3.x

Okay there must be a much more cleaner way to do this. I am still an amateur programmer but I feel like they have something that can shorten this. So basically I have this data set of numbers and I am counting the occurrences of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 as the first digit and then appending the count to a list. This definitely seems long that I have to do it in this way

```
countList = []
for elm in pop_num:
    s = str(elm)
    if (s[0] == '1'):
      count1 += 1 
    if (s[0] == '2'):
      count2 += 1
    if (s[0] == '3'):
      count3 += 1
    if (s[0] == '4'):
      count4 += 1
    if (s[0] == '5'):
      count5 += 1
    if (s[0] == '6'):
      count6 += 1
    if (s[0] == '7'):
      count7 += 1
    if (s[0] == '8'):
      count8 += 1
    if (s[0] == '9'):
      count9 += 1
  countList.append(count1)
  countList.append(count2)
  countList.append(count3)
  countList.append(count4)
  countList.append(count5)
  countList.append(count6)
  countList.append(count7)
  countList.append(count8)
  countList.append(count9)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two lines using `collections.Counter` (basically a special dict designed for counting things) and list comprehensions (a more concise syntax for writing simple loops).

Here's how I'd do it.

```
import collections

counts = collections.Counter(str(x)[0] for x in pop_num)
countList = [counts[str(i)] for i in range(1,10)]
```

Edit: Here's how to get equivalent functionality without using `collections`.

```
counts = {}
for x in pop_num:
    k = str(x)[0]
    counts.setdefault(k, 0)
    counts[k] += 1

countList = [counts[str(i)] for i in range(1,10)]
```

Comment: Mmmm I understand that, is there a way to do it without importing any other functions?

Comment: @Suliman Is there any reason you need to avoid the collections module? You could reimplement it yourself, but that just leads to more boilerplate code.

Comment: There isn't a reason I was just curious because I didn't know about the collections function before this so if more problems come up like this where I don't know if there is a module that exists for this type of thing I can figure out little tricks to make it shorter if that makes any sense

Comment: Anyway, I posted an example of how to do the same thing without any modules, but it's really just reinventing the wheel, since you'd normally use collections for this sort of thing. P.S. `collections` and `itertools` are two common utility modules that you should become familiar with. You'll probably need to use them again in the future.

Comment: @SulimanSharif "figuring out little tricks to make it shorter" - use the built-in libraries. It is the shortest way and involves the least amount of tricks; and it is the best way to learn the language.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys @Antimony it does seem I keep seeing itertools come up a lot and yeah I will definitely go more into this language.

Comment: @Suliman Are you going to accept the answer? It's good practice to accept an answer if it's helpful and answered the question.